# Is there a way to generate the random data using Interactive CPLEX?

Tags: random, cplex

Is there a way to generate the random data (as Triangular matrix, array with some restrictions in its values) using Interactive CPLEX?

Answer (score 1):

CPLEX doesn't include any feature that would generate random data for you.

Comment: If we use the CPLEX in the GAMS environment, will this problem be solved?

Comment: In opl Cplex you have a Rand function